# Laravel PHP: Single query to fetch User, UserPosts and PostComments

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and MySQL, i couldn't figure out how to use a single join query to get user, their posts, and post comments. I'm not sure if i'm doing it right, but there must be a better way to fetch posts and post comments in a structured way. This is what I've done so far. I'm using $username to lookout for every single post user has made in Posts table and then looping through each post to see if that specific post has any comments with post.id.

It's working perfectly, but i feel that it's a bit expensive way to loop through each single posts to find it's comments with an individual query. Is there a better way to do it in a single query and keep data structured so that i can easily populate my view?

```
public function user($username){
    $user = User::where('username',$username);

    if($user->count()){
        $user = $user->first();

        $posts = Posts::where('username', $username)->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->orderBy('at','DESC')->paginate(4);

        if(count($posts)>0){
            $i=0;
            foreach($posts as $data){

                $ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($data->created_at)).' '.$data->at;
                $comments = Comments::where('post_id',$posts[$i]->id)->get();
                $posts[$i]->at = ProfileController::getElapsedTime($ago);
                $posts[$i]->comments = $comments;

                $j=0;
                foreach($posts[$i]->comments as $comments){

                    $c_time = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($comments->created_at)).' '.$comments->at;
                    $posts[$i]->comments[$j]->at = ProfileController::getElapsedTime($c_time);

                    $comment_user = User::where('username', $posts[$i]->comments[$j]->comment_user)->first();

                    $posts[$i]->comments[$j]->user_dp   = $comment_user->dp_uri;
                    $posts[$i]->comments[$j]->name      = $comment_user->name;
                    $j++;
                }
                //echo $posts[$i]->comments.'<br><br>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
        return View::make('profile.posts')
            ->with('user',$user)->with('posts', $posts);
    }else{
        return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the Eloquent `with` function to eager-load the relationships.

Comment: http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins

Comment: Read about the relations in Eloquent. I'm not gonna even read the code you pasted, but from what you wrote in the beginning, you will be able to achieve what you want with this one-liner: `$user = User::with('posts.comments')->find($userId)` or instead of find `where('username', $username)->first()`

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out, now i'm eager loading the relations for user->posts->comments, but there's is this one problem. 
$user = User::with('posts.comments')->where('username',$username)->get();
It won't let me paginate the results, i tried ->paginate(10), it kinda goes into an infinite loop.

Comment: there are many ways to reduce the lines of code you have written here. But if you are concerned about performance, a single join-ed query would do because one large query is faster than many small queries.